# Want (internal) name for service while running nginx ingress controller kubernetes

Tags: mysql, nginx, kubernetes, kubeadm, kubernetes-ingress

Using kubeadm with a two-node cluster on VirtualBox Centos7 VMs. 
I have an app written in R and a mysql database each in their own pods. 
I've successfully followed [instructions to setup nginx ingress controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/deploy/README.md) so that the app can be reached outside the VMs, by my local machine. check :)

However, now when the app (R) tries to reach to the mysql service, the name doesn't resolve. Same with pinging 'mysql' from bash. This no longer works:

```
mydb<-dbConnect(MySQL(), user = 'root', password ='password',
                dbname = 'prototype', host = 'mysql')
```

Instead I have to use the pod's IP, which does work.

```
mydb<-dbConnect(MySQL(), user = 'root', password ='password',
                dbname = 'prototype', host = '10.244.1.233')
```

However, isn't this going to change upon reboots and system changes? I'd like a more static way to refer to the mysql db.

```
$ kubectl get endpoints
NAME         ENDPOINTS                             AGE
kubernetes   192.168.56.101:6443                   5h
mysql        10.244.1.233:3306                     41m
r-user-app   10.244.1.232:8787,10.244.1.232:3838   2h

$ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                         AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP                         5h
mysql        ClusterIP      10.96.138.132   <none>        3306/TCP                        28m
r-user-app   LoadBalancer   10.100.228.80   <pending>     3838:32467/TCP,8787:31754/TCP   2h

$ kubectl get ing
NAME         HOSTS              ADDRESS   PORTS     AGE
r-user-app   storage.test.com             80, 443   3h

$ kubectl describe service mysql
Name:              mysql
Namespace:         default
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=neurocore,tier=mysql
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.96.138.132
Port:              <unset>  3306/TCP
TargetPort:        3306/TCP
Endpoints:         10.244.1.236:3306
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>

 ps auxw | grep kube-proxy
root      1914  0.1  0.3  44848 21668 ?        Ssl  11:03   0:20 /usr/local/bin/kube-proxy --config=/var/lib/kube-proxy/config.conf
root     29218  0.0  0.0 112660   980 pts/1    R+   14:23   0:00 grep --color=auto kube-proxy

$iptables-save | grep mysql
-A KUBE-SEP-7P27CEQL6WJZRBQ5 -s 10.244.1.236/32 -m comment --comment "default/mysql:" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-7P27CEQL6WJZRBQ5 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/mysql:" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.244.1.236:3306
-A KUBE-SERVICES ! -s 10.244.0.0/16 -d 10.96.138.132/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/mysql: cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 3306 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.96.138.132/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/mysql: cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 3306 -j KUBE-SVC-M7XME3WTB36R42AM
-A KUBE-SVC-M7XME3WTB36R42AM -m comment --comment "default/mysql:" -j KUBE-SEP-7P27CEQL6WJZRBQ5
```

Comment: Can you share the result of the command `kubectl describe service mysql`?

Comment: @AntonKostenko edited the question with this info. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually an issue with **flannel**. When I switched to use [Weave](https://www.weave.works/docs/net/latest/kubernetes/kube-addon/) as the CNI, the service discovery and DNS kube works fine.

```
kubectl apply -f "https://cloud.weave.works/k8s/net?k8s-version=$(kubectl version | base64 | tr -d '\n')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your svc, you should be able to reach `mysql:3306` from within the cluster.

Have you tried `kubectl exec -it r-user-app bash` and pinging mysql from within the R app container? `host mysql` should return something like "mysql.cluster.local" has address 127.21.0.01" (example). Or return any error. If there isn't an error then maybe the dbConnect() doesn't like the host name?

Comment: `ping mysq`l and `ping mysql:3306` return unknown host. `ping 10.96.138.132` no response  :( I think because the ingress goes directly to the pod, and services are ignored then?

Comment: this is happening even without the ingress controller running `host mysql` returns: `Host mysql not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)`

Comment: That is odd. So nothing to do with dbConnect(). Clearly some DNS issue. Are the two containers on the same node?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your service is configured well.

> ping 10.96.138.132 no response :(

Each Service has a static address, so the situation when you cannot ping it is normal because that is just a virtual address and the requests to its processing is a bit different than the requests to the real addresses.

I see here only 2 reasons why you can have that problem:

1. Something wrong with DNS resolution in the container with your application. Try to use `10.96.138.132` as MySQL address instead of `mysql`. If it fixes your problem - that is a resolving problem. BTW, you can use Service IP instead of DNS, as I already told - it is static.
2. Something wrong with the forwarding rules. Check `kube-proxy` logs in `kube-system` namespace, maybe you will get any additional info for debugging.

Comment: no luck with these routes. cannot even ping the service from its own pod. ping 10.96.138.132 returns nothing. Put more info in the question. Does the nginx ingress controller do anything here?

Comment: Do not try to ping it, try to connect to that address from your app. About Ingress - no, it is processing requests from outside of the cluster. Your `iptables` rules look OK.

Comment: the ClusterIP does not work from the app either. Only the pod IP/endpoint. Maybe there is a way I can put that IP into an env variable for the other pod?

Comment: You can inject that UP to the environment variable, but pod IP is dynamic so it will work only before the next restart of the pod.